# Route in ASP.NET Core to React page get 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: reactjs, .net

I got some problem when trying to access the Route in ASP.NET
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHBlq.png)
Here is the Route to the the index.html in this folder, which is written in React, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7pRI.png)

But when I try to access the Route, it throw this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBhoj.png)..

Someone please help me to overcome this error!

It working fine when I running these folder indepently [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0krz.png).
I want it should show the web like this when access to the Route